# working with dotsMethods in function

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I want to "overload" a function, with a try and catch feature.

This is a "low-sense example" but if i solve this i have a solution for my real problem.

```
write.csv2 <- function(...) {
    utils::write.csv2(x = ..1,paste0("GET.THE.NAME.OF.THE.X_arg",".csv"))
}

write.csv2(x=mtcars)
```

The result of the above function call should end up in a CSV-file that is called "mtcars.csv"

If i call write.csv(x=DATAdata) there should be a csv called DATAdata.csv

I tried:

deparse(substitute()) and other stuff. Nothing worked to far.

## edit:

why does it not work?

```
write.csv2 <- function(...) {
    utils::write.csv2(x = ..1,file = paste0(deparse(substitute(..1)),".csv"))
}
write.csv2(x=mtcars)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to just use a dotlist? It's much easier to do the deparse/substitue magic if you use named parameters directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I convert `...` to a named list:

```
fun1 <- function(...){

 argv <- list(...)

 return(argv)

}
```

This means you can reference your variables from the list by the name you give them in the function call:

```
> fun1(filename='mtcars.csv')
$filename
[1] "mtcars.csv"
```

or a bit more sophisticated:

```
fun2 <- function(...){

 argv <- list(..)

 write.csv(argv$x,argv$filename)

}
```

With the call `fun2(x=runif(100),filename='randomnumbers.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

```
write.csv2 <- function(...) {
  call <- match.call(utils::write.csv2)
  call[[1]] <- utils::write.csv2
  call$file = paste0(deparse(call[[2]]), ".csv")
  eval.parent(call)
}
write.csv2(mtcars)
```

Here we capture call the call, re-write the `file=` parameter and pass it along to the real function.

Comment: i think this can get me somewhere. This is too much to understand atm